# Nginx - assigning non-root location to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

What I like to do is to proxy requests from `http://example.com/proxy/foo` to `http://localhost:8060/foo`

This config proxies `http://example.com/proxy/foo` to `http://localhost:8060/proxy/foo`

```
server {
    server_name example.com;


    location /proxy/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8040;                                                            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;


    location ^~ /proxy/ {
        rewrite ^/proxy(/.*)$ $1 break;    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8040;                                                            
    }

}
```